# how fix Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, installation

when i am trying to install `nodemon` I see this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g nodemon
C:\Users\lukos\.npm-global\nodemon -> C:\Users\lukos\.npm- 
global\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@2.0.6 postinstall C:\Users\lukos\.npm-global\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 
(node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
**npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})**

+ nodemon@2.0.6
updated 1 package in 6.746s
```

I tried clear npm cache but it didn't help, uninstall and try with other flags or without any.

optionally I see it:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install  nodemon

> nodemon@2.0.6 postinstall C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json'
npm WARN system32 No description
npm WARN system32 No repository field.
npm WARN system32 No README data
npm WARN system32 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ nodemon@2.0.6
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 182 packages in 0.849s

10 packages are looking for funding
   run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: This is not an error, nothing to fix.

Comment: That means `fsevents` is skipped doe to your windows platform. nothing to worry about, its a optional dependency.  test the installation with `nodemon --help`